# equality of plane sets

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have two sets

$\begin{align} A&=\{(t^2,2t):t\in \mathbb{R} \}\\
B&=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:y^2=4x\}\end{align}$

It asks to prove $A=B$, first checking $A\subseteq B$. We then let $(x,y)\in A$, and then $x=t^2$ & $y=2t$ for some $t\in\mathbb{R}$. Hence $y^2=4t^2=4x$.

My question is, how does $y^2=4t^2=4x$? How have we proved that $A\subseteq B$ with that?

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange! Next time onwards when you ask a question, please write on your attempts and approach to the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $y = 2t$ we have $y^2 = (2t)^2 = 4t^2$. Since $x=t^2$ we have $4t^2=4x$. Note that this means that $y^2 = 4x$ and so $(x,y) \in B$. The reason you proved $A \subseteq B$ is because you picked an arbitrary element of $A$ and showed it is also an element of $B$.

Comment: Now I understand it, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Proving $A \subset  B$ :

For every $(x,y) \in A$, you have some $t \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $x=t^2$ and $y=2t$. Now see that same $(x,y)$ is in $B$ as $y^{2}=4t^2$ and $x=t^2$ $\Rightarrow$ $y=4*x$. Hence $(x,y) \in B$.
$$\therefore A \subset B .$$

Proving $B \subset  A$ :

Consider an arbitrary $(x,y) \in B$, this means $y^2=4x$ (which means $x\geq 0$). Now define $x=t^2$ for some suitable $t \in \mathbb{R}$. This implies $x=t^2$ and $y=2t$ or $x=t^2$ and $y=-2t$. Both of these $(x,y) \in A$. 
$$ \therefore B \subset  A .$$
$$ \text{Now} A \subset B  \text{ and } B \subset  A \Rightarrow A=B.$$

Answer (score 0):

1) Every  point on $A$ is a point on $B$.

$A= ${$(t^2,2t);$ $t \in \mathbb{R}$}.

$x=t^2;$  $y= 2t.$

Note :  $0 \le  x$; and  $y \in \mathbb{R}.$

$t = ^+_- √x$  $\rightarrow$

$y =2 (^+_- √x)$, or.  $y^2 = 4x.$

2) Every point on $B$ is a point on $A$.

$B= ${ $(x,y): y^2 = 4x$},  where

$0 \le x;$ and $y \in \mathbb{R}$.

Choose $y=2t$ , $t \in \mathbb{R}$, then

$(t^2,2 t) \in A.$